# Why can't I use inherited objects in my inherited class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
    class Vehicle  // base class (parent) 
    {
      public string brand = "Ford";  // Vehicle field
      public void honk()             // Vehicle method 
      {                    
        Console.WriteLine("Tuut, tuut!");
      }
    }
    
    class Car : Vehicle  // derived class (child)
    {
      public string modelName = "Mustang";  // Car field
      brand = "WHY İS NOT ??? "; // Error.

  public void honk(); // Error.
}
```

Can't I do that? Does the class we inherit have its functions, methods, and variables? Did I learn something wrong?

Note; It works within the main function.

I've been dealing with this for a long time. : / (3+ hours)

Comment: And Btw;  Vehicle _a = new Vehicle(); _a. or  // its again don't work :/ 
or Car_a = new Car(); _a. // Same

Comment: what exactly do you *expect*  `public void honk();` to do?

Comment: Yes I can not use in Car class, I want use honk() function in Car.

Comment: You can call members only within other members, e.g. methods. So you need to call `honk` within a method

Comment: To call `honk` use just **`honk();`** instead of `public void honk();`. Also it needs to be in a method, not at the class level. Also put `brand = "...";` in a method, or in a constructor (which is a special method).

Comment: And `brand = "WHY İS NOT ??? "` fails for a similar reason - that's just an assignment statement (not a declaration) in a class declaration. You can't just write statements like that - they have to be within a method, or a constructor, or a property accessor body etc. Note that that has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: As an aside, there are two really quite different errors here - one about `honk` and one about `brand`. It would really help if you could keep each post to *one* error.

Comment: You can´t do much at the class-level. One of the core-concepts of OOP is that everything needs to be done within **members** of a class, e.g. calling other members like methods, or assigning variables. While a few statements are also allowed *outside* methods, that does not apply to your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just write to a field (defined in a base class) from the derived class like:

```
brand = "WHY İS NOT ??? "; // Error.
```

...because you aren't definining a *new* field, rather you are attempting to *change* `brand` defined in the the base class `Vehicle`.  Unfortunately the way it is written, the compiler thinks it's an *orphaned* assignment.  It should exist in a in a **method** or **constructor**.

Try placing it in a constructor:

```
class Car : Vehicle  // derived class (child)
{
      public string modelName = "Mustang";  // Car field

      public Car()
      {
          brand = "Acme"; 
      }

      public void honk() {}
}
```

### Honk

```
public void honk(); // Error.
```

The problem here is that your method has no body.  Whilst you can do that in an `interface` you can't in a non-abstract method belonging to a class.

Give it a minimal one like so:

```
public override void honk() { }
```

...or:

```
public override void honk() 
{
   // same thing but formatted differently
}
```

Notice there is a new `override`.  If you want a new implementation of `honk` in a derived class it's best to make the method `virtual`.

i.e.

```
class Vehicle  // base class (parent) 
    {
      // ...

      public virtual void honk()           
      {                    
        Console.WriteLine("Tuut, tuut!");
      }

      // ...
    }
```

Alternatively you can use `new` instead of `override` but there are [gotchas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords).

Comment: Yayyy its work \o/ This works. I feel so stupid for wasting so much time on it. So why do we need to write inside the function?

Comment: @PofiduPufuduk lol no worries.  I've updated my answer to give you more details

Comment: Thanks  My hero:3 <3

Comment: @PofiduPufuduk anytime.  Don't forget to accept as answer as it helps feed the kiddies....if I had kiddies